# Extension of measurable function from dense subset

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, riemannian-geometry, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $M$ be a compact riemannian manifold equipped with a geodesic distance  and let $\mathcal{B}(M)$ be the borel sigma algebra generated by the geodesic distance. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space that arises from a compact metric space $(\Omega,d)$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the borel sigma algebra. Let $\tilde{\Omega}$ be a countable dense subset of $\Omega$.

We would like to answer to the following question:
Let:
$$f \colon (\tilde{\Omega},\mathcal{F}_{\rvert\tilde{\Omega}}) \to (M,\mathcal{B}(M))$$
be a measurable function.
Is it possible to construct a function
$$g \colon  (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \to (M,\mathcal{B}(M)) $$
with the property that $g$ is measurable, $g_{\rvert\tilde{\Omega}}= f$ and,
if $\omega \in \Omega\setminus \tilde{\Omega}$, then

$$g(\omega)= \lim_{n \to \infty}f(\omega_n) $$

for a sequence  $ \{\omega_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \tilde{\Omega}$ such that $\omega_n \to \omega$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\om\omega\newcommand\Om\Omega\newcommand\tom{{\tilde\omega}}\newcommand\tOm{\tilde\Omega}\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\vpi}{\varphi}\newcommand\ol\overline\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}$Take any $m\in\text{Im}(f)$ and then let
$$g(\om):=
\begin{cases}
f(\om)&\text{ if }\om\in\tOm, \\ 
m&\text{ if }\om\in\Om\setminus\tOm.  
\end{cases}$$
The $g$ will have the desired properties.

---

The OP has changed the question, thus invalidating the answer above.

The answer to the changed question is still yes, but the construction is much more complicated.

Since the manifold $M$ is compact, it has a finite [atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Atlases) $A:=\{(U_i,\vpi_i)\colon i\in[k]\}$, where $[k]:=\{i\in\N\colon i\le k\}$, with bounded images $\vpi_i(U_i)$ of the $U_i$'s. Without loss of generality (wlog), $A$ is a refinement of another atlas $\{(V_i,\psi_i)\colon i\in[k]\}$ of $M$ in the sense that $\ol{U_i}\subseteq V_i$ and $\vpi_i=\psi_i|_{U_i}$ for all $i$, where $\ol S$ denotes the closure of a set $S$ and $|_S$ denotes the restriction to $S$.

For each $i\in[k]$, let
\begin{equation}
    \hat\Om_i:=f^{-1}(U_i), \quad 
    \Om_i:=\ol{\hat\Om_i}\setminus\bigcup_{j\in[k-1]}\ol{\hat\Om_j}, \quad 
    \tOm_i:=\hat\Om_i\cap\Om_i.  
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
    \Om=\bigcup_{i\in[k]}\Om_i 
\end{equation}
(because $M=\bigcup_{i\in[k]}U_i$, whence $\tOm=\bigcup_{i\in[k]}\hat\Om_i$, whence  $\Om=\ol\tOm=\ol{\bigcup_{i\in[k]}\hat\Om_i}=\bigcup_{i\in[k]}\ol{\hat\Om_i}=\bigcup_{i\in[k]}\Om_i$);

- the $\Om_i$'s are pairwise disjoint and measurable;
- $\tOm_i$ is countable and dense in $\Om_i$ for each $i$ (because the $\ol{\hat\Om_i}$'s are closed sets);
- $f(\tOm_i)\subseteq U_i$ for each $i$.

So, it suffices to construct the function $g$ locally -- that is, separately on each $\Om_i$. So, to simplify notations in what follows, fix any $i\in[k]$ and let

- $U:=U_i$, $\vpi:=\vpi_i$, and $\psi:=\psi_i$.
- Also, re-define $\Om$ and $\tOm$ by letting them, respectively, denote $\Om_i$ and $\tOm_i$, from now on.

In other words, we are going to omit the subscript ${}_i$ everywhere in what follows.

Let $n$ denote the dimension of the manifold $M$, so that
\begin{equation}
    \vpi(m)=(\vpi^1(m),\dots,\vpi^n(m))\in\R^n
\end{equation}
for some real-valued functions $\vpi^1,\dots,\vpi^n$ and all $m\in U$.
For $j\in[n]$, let
\begin{equation}
    h_j:=\vpi^j\circ f,\quad\text{so that }h_j\colon\tOm\to\R. 
\end{equation}

Take any real $\ep>0$. For each $\om\in\Om$, let
\begin{equation}
    H_\ep(\om):=\vpi(f(\tOm\cap B_\om(\ep)))
    =\{h(\tom)\colon\tom\in\tOm\cap B_\om(\ep)\},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    h(\tom):=\vpi(f(\tom))=(h_1(\tom),\dots,h_n(\tom))
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    B_\om(\ep):=\{\tau\in\Om\colon d(\tau,\om)<\ep\}. 
\end{equation}
Since the map $\vpi$ is continuous and $f(\tOm\cap B_\om(\ep))\subseteq\ol U\subseteq M$, the set $\ol{H_\ep(\om)}$ is a compact  subset of $\R^n$. So, there is a unique maximum, say
\begin{equation}
    \ol h_\ep(\om)=(\ol h_{1,\ep}(\om),\dots,\ol h_{n,\ep}(\om))\in\R^n, 
\end{equation}
of the set $\ol{H_\ep(\om)}$ with respect to the ([total/linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)) [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

Note that for any real $c_1$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\ol h_{1,\ep}(\om)\le c_1 \\  
    &\iff \\ 
    &\forall\tom\in\tOm\quad \tom\in B_\om(\ep)\implies h_1(\tom)\le c_1,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\ol h_{1,\ep}(\om)\le c_1 \\  
    &\iff \\ 
    &\forall\tom\in\tOm\quad \om\in B_\tom(\ep)\implies h_1(\tom)\le c_1,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Letting $\Q_{++}:=\Q\cap(0,\infty)$,
by induction on $n$ one can show that for $n\ge2$ and any real $c_1,\dots,c_n$
\begin{align*}
    &\ol h_{1,\ep}(\om)\le c_1\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ \ol h_{n,\ep}(\om)\le c_n \\ 
    &\iff \\ 
&   \begin{aligned}
&   \ol h_{1,\ep}(\om)\le c_1\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ \ol h_{n-1,\ep}(\om)\le c_{n-1} \\ 
&\&\ \forall\de_n\in\Q_{++}\ \exists \de_1,\dots,\de_{n-1}\in\Q_{++}\ 
    \forall\tom\in\tOm\quad  \\ 
    &\quad\  \om\in B_\tom(\ep) \\ 
    &\quad\  \implies 
    (h_1(\tom)\ge c_1-\de_1\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\  h_{n-1}(\tom)\ge c_{n-1}-\de_{n-1} \\ 
&\qquad\qquad   \implies
    h_n(\tom)\le c_n+\de_n). 
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
Therefore and because the balls $B_\tom(\ep)$ are measurable whereas the sets $\Q_{++}$ and $\tOm$ are countable, we conclude that the $\R^n$-valued function $\ol h_\ep$ is measurable.

Moreover, since the set $H_\ep(\om)$ is nondecreasing in $\ep$, so is the maximum $\ol h_\ep(\om)$ of the set $\ol{H_\ep(\om)}$. So, there is a pointwise limit $\ol h$ of $\ol h_\ep$: for each $\om\in\Om$,
\begin{equation}
    \ol h(\om):=\lim_{\ep\downarrow0}\ol h_\ep(\om) 
\end{equation}
and, hence, by the continuity of the map $\psi^{-1}$,
\begin{equation}
    g(\om):=\psi^{-1}(\ol h(\om))=\lim_{\ep\downarrow0}\psi^{-1}(\ol h_\ep(\om)).  
\end{equation}

The function $\ol h$ is measurable, as the pointwise limit of the measurable functions $\ol h_\ep$. Also, the continuous map $\psi^{-1}$ is measurable. So, $g=\psi^{-1}\circ \ol h$ is measurable.

The maximum $\ol h_\ep(\om)$ of the set $\ol{H_\ep(\om)}$ is of course in $\ol{H_\ep(\om)}$ and hence $\ol h_\ep(\om)=\lim_{r\to\infty}h(\tom_{\ep,\om,r})$ -- for each real $\ep>0$, each $\om\in\Om$, and some sequence $(\tom_{\ep,\om,r})_{r\in\N}$ in $\tOm\cap B_\om(\ep)$.

Since $\psi^{-1}$ is continuous and $\psi^{-1}(h(\tom))=f(\tom)$ for all $\tom\in\tOm$, we have
\begin{equation}
    g(\om)=\lim_{\ep\downarrow0}\psi^{-1}(\lim_{r\to\infty}h(\tom_{\ep,\om,r}))
    =\lim_{\ep\downarrow0}\lim_{r\to\infty}\psi^{-1}(h(\tom_{\ep,\om,r}))
    =\lim_{\ep\downarrow0}\lim_{r\to\infty}f(\tom_{\ep,\om,r}).  
\end{equation}
So, for each $\om\in\Om$ there is a sequence $(r_t(\om))_{t\in\N}$ in $\N$ such that
\begin{equation}
    g(\om)
    =\lim_{t\to\infty}f(\tom_{1/t,\om,r_t(\om)}).  
\end{equation}
Moreover, $\tom_{1/t,\om,r_t(\om)}\in B_\om(1/t)$ and hence $\tom_{1/t,\om,r_t(\om)}\to\om$ as $t\to\infty$. $\quad\Box$

*Remark:* Some of the conditions here can be relaxed. In particular, we do not need $M$ to be a Riemannian manifold or any manifold at all. In particular, it suffices that $M$ be any topological space admitting a finite open cover $\{U_i\colon i\in[k]\}$ with homeomorphisms $\psi_i$ of $\ol{U_i}$ onto compact domains $D_i\subset\R^{n_i}$, for each $i\in[k]$.

Comment: Thanks, I asked the question in the worst possible way

Comment: Why does $m$ equal $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(\omega_n)$ for some sequence $(\omega_n)_n$ in $\tilde\Omega$ converging to $\omega$ for every $\omega \in \Omega \setminus \tilde\Omega$?

Comment: @LSpice : The answer is to the original version of the question, without the condition $g(\omega)= \lim_{n \to \infty}f(\omega_n) $.

Comment: @GiuseppeTenaglia, you should not change the question after answers have been posted (but instead post a new question); but, if you do anyway, then you should mention explicitly in the question body that you have done so.

Comment: The changed question has been answered, too.

Comment: this proof is amazing. How did you come up with the idea of taking the maximum of a lexicographic order?

Comment: @GiuseppeTenaglia : Thank you for your appreciation. I started with the one-dimensional case, where the maximum of any compact set exists. An order in the multidimensional case with respect to which any compact set has a unique maximum is the lexicographic one. I wanted the uniqueness, because otherwise it seemed hard to make a measurable selection.